# Troubleshooting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING" in echo statement

Tags: php, echo

I am back to php after like 5 years and I need help with the following please:) It keeps telling me the error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in header.php** (in the first echo invoke)

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE disabled=0 ORDER BY orderx ASC") or die(mysql_error());
$i=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<li class='sddm'.$i.' '.$row[extra].'"><a href="'.link_text($row[link]).'" onmouseover=\"mopen('m2')\" onmouseout=\"mclosetime()\">'.link_text($row[link]).'</a>";
    echo "<div id='m2' onmouseover='mcancelclosetime()' onmouseout='mclosetime()'>";
    echo "<a href='#'>ASP Dropdown</a>";
    echo "<a href='#'>Pulldown menu</a>";
    echo "<a href='#'>AJAX dropdown</a>";
    echo "<a href='#'>DIV dropdown</a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</li>";

    <!--echo '<li class="sddm'.$i.' '.$row[extra].'"><a href="'.link_text($row[link]).'">'.$row[title.langfix()].'</a>';-->
    echo'</li>';
    $i++;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your quotes are all out of whack:

```
echo "<li class='sddm'.$i.' '.$row[extra].'"><a href="'.link_text($row[link]).'"
```

Should be

```
echo '<li class="sddm"'.$i.' '.$row[extra].'"><a href="'.link_text($row[link]).'"
```

You can swap out the quotes accordingly if you wish to use single quotes in your HTML but this should show you where your error lies.

Comment: Did you check all of your quotes to make sure they're correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<li class="sddm'.$i.' '.$row[extra].'"><a href="'.link_text($row["link"]).'" onmouseover="mopen(\'m2\')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">'.link_text($row["link"]).'</a>';
echo '<div id=\'m2\' onmouseover=\'mcancelclosetime()\' onmouseout=\'mclosetime()\'>';
echo '<a href=\'#\'>ASP Dropdown</a>';
echo "<a href='#'>Pulldown menu</a>";
echo "<a href='#'>AJAX dropdown</a>";
echo "<a href='#'>DIV dropdown</a>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</li>";

echo '<li class="sddm'.$i.' '.$row["extra"].'"><a href="'.link_text($row[link]).'">'.$row["title"].langfix().'</a>';
echo'</li>';
$i++;
```

Comment: I have updated the code, notice that the field names from mysql need quotes too.

Answer (score 0):

When you have complex quotes to manage, consider using [`printf()`](http://php.net/printf):

```
printf(
  '<li class="sddm%d" %s><a href="%s" onmouseover="mopen(\'m2\')" onmouseout="mclosetime();">'
    , $i
    , htmlentities($row['extra'])
    , htmlentities(link_text($row['link']))
);
```

Comment: Might as well post that as a separate answer.  Almost all of the token 'how do I echo a string with quotes' answers are accounted for here.

Answer (score 0):

`echo <<<END` newline content newline `END;` works well and also parses variables and ignores quotes until `END;`.